# Jquery slideToggle() - toggle all

Tags: jquery

I have a page where there are questions with answers hidden underneath them. When someone clicks on a question, the answer slides down (this is a seperate function which works fine). When clicked again, it returns to its hidden state.

When an answer is already open, this function runs and opens all the closed answers but closes all the open answers.

I want it to open all and keep the open answers open, and close all and keep the closed answers closed.

```
  <div id="hideMenu">
      <span style="display: inline;" class="title">Afficher
      tout</span>
      <span class="title" style="display: none;">Cacher
      tout</span>
      <span class="arrow"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="MppWP">
      <ul>
           <li class="MppAccordion">
                <h3 class="MppWPTitle grey1">
                <span class="MppOrder">1</span>Pr&#233;paration
                de l'appel &#224; candidatures (1er tour)
                <span class="arrow"></span></h3>
                <ul style="display: none;"
                class="MppWPContent">
                     <li>aaaaa</li></ul></li>

           <li class="MppAccordion">
                <h3 class="MppWPTitle grey1">
                <span class="MppOrder">1</span>Pr&#233;paration
                de l'appel &#224; candidatures (1er tour)
                <span class="arrow"></span></h3>
                <ul style="display: none;"
                class="MppWPContent">
                     <li>aaaaa</li></ul></li>
     </ul>
   </div>



$('#hideMenu').click(function () {
    //alert("ici");
    $(this).find(".title").toggle().end()
           .find('arrow').toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.MppWP .MppAccordion .MppWPContent').slideToggle("normal").end()  
           .children('.arrow').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: could you be more precise, what typo is missing in the selector ?

Comment: I had removed my comment, it seems `arrow` is a class name, you are missing `.` => `.find('arrow')`. Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: the result is the same, it doesn't works

Comment: Shouldn't we see the structure of your markup? Your question as it is doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: i edit my post, it help us ?

Comment: Yes, I have used `slideDown` instead of `slideToggle`, is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/KS6gK/

Answer (score 0):

From what you have mentioned here, i think you could use `:visible` selector to find which one is visible and `:hidden` to find hidden element and do the toggle thing.